# Transform beta feature and nested aggregation elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

TLDR : how to nested aggregation with transforms ? More generally : how to store aggregations at index time ?

I am trying to use the new beta feature transform of elasticsearch.
My aggregation is the following :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "event": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "site_document"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inspection_per_agency": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "site_document.document_type_kw"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "action_per_event_type": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "site_document.id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this the transformation I have created

```
PUT /_transform/transformation1
{
  "source": {
    "index": "site_source"
    }
    ,
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "id": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "site_document"
        },
        "terms": {
          "field": "site_document.document_type_kw"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "count_id": { 
        "nested": {
          "path": "site_document"
        },
        "value_count": {
          "field": "site_document.id" }
      }

    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "site_dest"
  },
  "frequency": "1s"
}
```

This returns an error

```
No enum constant org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.transform.transforms.pivot.SingleGroupSource.Type.NESTED
```

Do you know what the syntax should be ?

More details below (mapping and data example):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "site_name_kw": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "govz_normalizer",
        "copy_to": "site_name_txt"
      },
      "site_document": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "document_type_kw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "govz_normalizer",
            "copy_to": "site_document_type_txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
  {
  "id": 67,
  "site_name_kw": "site1",
  "site_document": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "document_type_kw": "type1"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "document_type_kw": "type2"
    },
    {
      "id": 56,
      "document_type_kw": "type3"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "document_type_kw": "type1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: After searching more about this, Transform doesn't provide nested aggregations right now. We are going to compute those aggregations on the back end side, it looks like the best thing to do now, until Elasticsearch gives better APIs to store aggregations. Roll-up API look interesting for what we try to achieve, but it's not a stable feature either

Comment: It could very well be that nested aggs aren't implemented yet. But if they were, I suspect they'd adhere to the syntax spec and from what it looks like, you've forgotten the agg name: https://prnt.sc/rsjoy7 vs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations. Though your first agg is syntactically correct.

Comment: thank you for the syntax suggestion. I have had a call with the elastic support and it looks like it's not handled right now anyway